# Flutter ElevatedButton with Image cover

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to create a rounded `ElevatedButton` with an image background cover as the following:

[image]

Right now my `ElevatedButton` show that result:

[image]

```
ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(shape: const StadiumBorder()),
      child: Image.network('url...', fit: BoxFit.cover),
    )
```

Can someone give me an example of how to add a background image to a rounded `ElevatedButton`?

Comment: Have you tried clipping?

Comment: Clipping the image didn't help since ElevatedButton does not fit itself its children. Also trying to Image BoxFit.cover didn't fit the ElevatedButton completely as you can see from my example :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `clipBehavior` and `padding` like this:

```
SizedBox(
    height: 100,
    child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,// <--add this
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0), // <--add this
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero, // <--add this
        ),         
        child: Image.network('url...', fit: BoxFit.cover),
    ),
),
```

[image]

Comment: very good. but now the splash is disappearing. how can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

you can't use the image in your ElevatedButton but you can use **IconButton** and **Container** in flutter for the image...

```
IconButton(
  icon: Image.asset('path/the_image.png'),
  iconSize: 50,
  onPressed: () {},
)
```

and

```
Container(child: ConstrainedBox(
constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
child: FlatButton(
         onPressed: null,
         padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
         child: Image.asset('path/the_image.png'))))
```

Comment: Hey @EhtiXham thanks for your reply and welcome to the StackOverflow community. IconButton, InkWell, and Gesture do not act (and are not as simple to make them act) the same as ElevatedButton. I was wondering if there is a viable solution in the context of ElevatedButton explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

### You can use Elevated Button.

- Ensure all padding is removed from the parent `Elevated button` by setting the padding in `ElevatedButton.styleFrom` padding param; Apply new material state edge insets of all zero

> MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.zero)

- Set `Stack.fit` to `StackFit.streched` wrap the `Icon` with `Center` widget.
- Set background image `frameBuilder` to a wrapper that will apply `const StadiumBorder()` to the image: `Decorated box`

---

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
     shape: const StadiumBorder(),
     padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.zero)
  ),
  child: Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  children: [
      Image.network(
        'url...', 
        fit: BoxFit.cover
        frameBuilder: (c, child, frame, sync) {
          return DecoratedBox(
            ...,
            shape: const StadiumBorder(),
            child: child
          )
        }
      ),
      const Icon(Icons.play_arrow, color: Colors.white)
    ],
  )
)
```

Now this should do...

*Check out [r-css](https://github.com/rey-xi/r_css): Easy to use flutter templates. Package available on Pub.dev*

Answer (score 0):

***I*** can't find any way to make the background of the `ElevatedButton` an image(maybe someone can find it). Try making a ***self-made*** button with multiple widgets, namely `GestureDetector`, `SizedBox`, `Card` and `Container`.

Try the following code:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {},
  child: SizedBox(
    height: 150,
    width: 250,
    child: Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
      ),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
          image: const DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            image: NetworkImage(
              'url...',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

The more better way to add a button behind the image or text to navigate the screen is to close the widget inside the `GestureDetector` with its property `onTap`. In this way you are able to add link behind to everything including image, text, container, column, icon etc

```
GestureDectector( 
     onTap: (){}
child: Image(
    image: AssetImage("")
  )
)
```

Comment: This solution does not provide full ElevatedButton capabilities. It's just an Image with an action response.